# Do edits in iPhone notes have a timestamp?

Tags: ios, notes.app

I'm trying to find proof I wrote something in a Note on a certain date. But I use this particular Note all the time and I've made many updates since the time I'm trying to prove I wrote a specific section.

Is there any way to get a Time Signature for when I made a specific entry into a long-running note?